# Flickering kinect camera image using OpenNI

Tags: openni-kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been running an OpenNI Kinect node for approximate two hours and noticed that the camera image started to flicker, resulting in a pointcloud with black points.

When looking on the camera image in Rviz it flickered as I said.
Does anyone else experience this problem and know what it is related to?

- Nicklas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31118/flickering-kinect-camera-image-using-openni/) by [Nicklas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2116/nicklas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-04-03**:
Yes, when i have the Kinect running for a longer time (>1 hour), I sometimes experience the same phenomenon. A driver restart solves this iirc. Nevertheless could this be quite frustrating when doing some long-term exploration/mapping...

**Comment by [Yuto Inagaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/8746/yuto-inagaki/) on 2013-12-07**:
I had same phenomenon  too, when I launch openni.launch for Kinect which is in openni_launch after some minuties(20~30minutes). Is this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a bug. Are you running [openni](http://ros.org/wiki/openni) or [openni_kinect](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect)?

- The `openni` package is deprecated, so try `openni_kinect` instead.
- If you already use `openni_kinect`, open a defect ticket. Although the defect may be in hardware, the driver might be able to perform some recovery action (assuming we can reproduce the problem).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0